# Sliding effect using jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

below is my code:

html:

```
<div>
    <div id="div1">12345</div>
    <div id="div2">67890</div>
    <div id="div3"><a href="#" id="slide">abcde</a></div>
    <div id="pad" style="display:none;">1234567890</div> 
</div>
```

css:

```
#div1{width: 150px; height:50px; background-color: red;}
#div2{width: 150px; height:100px; background-color: yellow;}
#div3, #pad{width: 150px; height:20px; background-color: grey;}
#pad{height: 50px;}
```

js:

```
        $("#slide").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
          if($("#div2").hasClass("toggled")) {
             $("#div2").animate({"height": "100px"}, function() {
                 $("#pad").hide();}).removeClass("toggled"); 
          } 
          else {
            $("#div2").animate({"height": "40px"}, function() {
            $("#pad").show();}).addClass("toggled"); 
          }
       });
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fmcb45hr/3/)

When I press the link, a grey div will slide up. Kinda like a keypad sliding up when user press the link.

But it kinda look weird. The "pad" div only show after the grey div slide up. And it only will hide after sliding down. What I want is for the "pad" to have a slide up and slide down effect, like opening and closing a drawer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slideDown/Up to show the `pad` element and don't wait for the slide animation to finish to start the animation of `pad`

```js
$("#slide").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#div2").hasClass("toggled")) {
    $("#div2").animate({
      "height": "100px"
    }).removeClass("toggled");
    $("#pad").slideUp();
  } else {
    $("#div2").animate({
      "height": "40px"
    }).addClass("toggled");
    $("#pad").slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#div3,
#pad {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}
#pad {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="div1">12345</div>
  <div id="div2">67890</div>
  <div id="div3"><a href="#" id="slide">abcde</a></div>
  <div id="pad" style="display:none;">1234567890</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. That's brilliant! I don't know there is this slideUp() and slideDown() features.